# How to annotate on a Django model's M2M field and get a list of distinct instances?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two Django models `Profile` and `Device` with a ManyToMany relationship with one another like so:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Device, related_name='profiles')
```

I am trying to use `annotate()` and `Count()` to query on all profiles that have 1 or more devices like this:

```py
profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(dev_count=Count('devices')).filter(dev_count__gt=1)
```

This is great, it gives me a `QuerySet` with all the profiles (4500+) with one or more devices, as expected.

Next, because of the M2M relationship, I would like to get a list of all the distinct devices among all the profiles from the previous queryset.
All of my failed attempts below return an empty queryset. I have read the documentation on `values`, `values_list`, and `annotate` but I still can't figure out how to make the correct query here.

```py
devices = profiles.values('devices').distinct()
devices = profiles.values_list('devices', flat=True).distinct()
```

I have also tried to do it in one go:

```py
devices = (
    Profile.objects.values_list('devices', flat=True)
                .annotate(dev_count=Count('devices'))
                .filter(dev_count__gt=1)
                .distinct()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not work with `.values()` since that that item appears both in the `SELECT` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause, so then you start mentioning the field, and hence the `COUNT(devices)` will return `1` for each group.

You can filter on the `Device`s that are linked to at least one of these `Profile`s with:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(
    dev_count=Count('devices')
).filter(dev_count__gt=1)

devices = Device.objects.filter(profile__in=profiles).distinct()
```

For some SQL dialects, usually MySQL it is better to first materialize the list of `profile`s and not work with a subquery, so:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(
    dev_count=Count('devices')
).filter(dev_count__gt=1)
profiles_list = list(profiles)

devices = Device.objects.filter(profile__in=profiles_list).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the quick explanation on `values()`. It works like a charm.